# Issues printing an estimator.predict tensor

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow-estimator

I am currently using tf 1.4, and I need help looking at the predictions of a `tf.contrib.factorization.KMeansClustering` estimator. My current code segment looks like:

```
km = KMeansClustering(num_clusters=8,initial_clusters=KMeansClustering.KMEANS_PLUS_PLUS_INIT,model_dir=MODEL,relative_tolerance=0.01)

result = km.train(input_fn=lambda: gen_input(body))

input_fn = tf.estimator.inputs.pandas_input_fn(x={'x':tst}, shuffle=False)

y = result.predict(input_fn)
```

Where body and tst are pandas dataframes. `print(y)` gives:

```
<generator object Estimator.predict at 0x11ebecba0>
```

And trying things that I've searched up like calling `print(list(y))`, `print(next(y))` or iterating through y like:

```
for i in y:
    ...

for i in y.items():
    ...

for i in enumerate(y):
    ...
```

etc, gives the error `TypeError: data must be either a numpy array or pandas DataFrame if pandas is installed; got dict`. I can't find any other ways to try and print this online. Thanks

Answer (score -1):

Your code is too less to confirm on what's wrong/missing. Also at least a full stack trace is expected. This answer may prove to be well off after you add more information.

Is it that you're expecting the call to `pandas_input_fn` return something else than what you expect? It returns a function with signature `()->(dict of features, target)` See [docs](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r1.1/api_docs/python/tf/estimator/inputs/pandas_input_fn) for details.

Also, it you don't seem to be running a TensorFlow `session`. Until you do so, all tensors, computations (predictions in your case) etc are just part of a graph, they will have values only after running a TF session.

See these [docs](https://www.tensorflow.org/programmers_guide/graphs) for more details.